# Listen for new Audio Sessions as they appear in the windows Volume mixer

Tags: c#, winapi, audio

Windows built in Volume Mixer displays current programs outputting sound. How would I similarly implement such a feature in c#?

I am able to loop through every audio session using Windows Core Audio API, however to get updates on when audio sessions either start or end, I would need to run an infinite loop.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Here's an image of the windows volume mixer]

Comment: How about a timer that periodically checks for updates?

Comment: I was thinking about that but I wasn't sure if there was a more elegant method.

Comment: [`IAudioSessionNotification::OnSessionCreated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370973) method notifies the registered processes that the audio session has been created.

Comment: The documentation on that only references c ++, how would I use it in C#?

Comment: The API is native, so you consume that from C# via respective definitions. For example you can leverage those from NAudio, [see here](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/10e188dbb71166afa328de76d0a0240996d7e265/NAudio/CoreAudioApi/Interfaces/IAudioSessionNotification.cs).

Comment: Or you can check how [this project](https://github.com/Klocman/Automatic-Volume-Mixer/blob/f4dd0982ee9d0032b90aa9704ffbea9d23d13d66/Automatic%20Volume%20Mixer/Daemon/SessionCreatedNotification.cs) does the job.